# How to set limits (1 or 2) When wanting a random number?

Tags: java, random

I am attempting to create a method where a user predicts if a simulated coin toss will be heads or tails. I am having trouble getting the random number to assign to just 1 or 2 (for heads of tails). I believe my attempt(code below) is giving me 0, 1 and 2.

```
public static void coinToss(String call){
        //setting up random
        Random random = new Random();

        //set user guess to numeric value
        int guessNo=0;


        if (call.equalsIgnoreCase("heads")){
            guessNo=1;
        }else if (call.equalsIgnoreCase("tails")){
            guessNo=2;
        }else System.out.println("Invalid. Enter either heads or tails");

        //setting result for coin toss 
        **int result = random.nextInt(2);**
        System.out.println("Trace: numberic result is:" + result);

        //if...else statement to print results of coin toss
        if (result==1){
            System.out.println("Result: heads");
        }else if (result==2){
            System.out.println("Result: Tails");
        }else System.out.println("Invalid result");

        if (guessNo==result){
            System.out.println("Guess Correct");
        }else System.out.println("Guess incorrect");

    }//method end
```

I am a relative java newbie (obviously!) so Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int result = (random.nextInt(2))+1;` is what you might want to try.

Comment: Our two answers put together make for one complete answer :)

Comment: well, I wouldn't mind if you put the code in your answer to make it complete :-), I will then delete my answer @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I saw your profile a minute ago, you got "inge-mark.hr" as your website. Is inge your surname?

Comment: No, I use my real name. That's just the firm I work for (no surnames involved).

Comment: Ah alright :-), My full name is Aniket Inge.. so got me thinking

Comment: If you worked for us, everyone would take you for the head guy :)

Comment: Haha, that would be awesome - wouldn't it? :D. Thanks. I be deleting this answer now

Comment: Thanks to both of you I got my solution!

Answer (score 2):

The answers suggesting adding one to the nextInt(2) result are correct, but may not be the right long term strategy. In many ways, Java prefers sequences of numbers to start, whenever possible, at 0. For example, array index values run from 0 through length-1.

It may be better to change your internal encoding of the heads/tails to use [0,1] rather than [1,2], and use the nextInt result directly.

Comment: I'll second this. If you use 0/1 encoding rather than 1/2, it's less work (although not by much), but it's also useful if you want to generalize by doing something like counting how many heads or tails you get over a sequence of throws. Just sum up the outcomes directly to get the total of whichever you encoded as 1.  Clearly the other outcome has a count of `N - total`, where `N` is the number of flips. This is so useful it has its own name in different fields - Bernoulli random variable in probability, or indicator variable in general mathematics.

Comment: Thanks for yout input! I decided to use "int result = (random.nextInt(2))+1;" as im still fairly new to Java. Next time I will try the solution using the answer you have provided so i know both ways! :)

Answer (score 1):

As documented, `Random::nextInt` supplies a random number between 0 (inclusive) and the specified upper limit (exclusive). You must therefore first obtain a random number from the range `[0,2>` and then add 1 to that.